# Core data：TableViewの行削除後に空のTableViewCellが残る

Tags: uitableview, coredata

TableViewに表示されているname(CoreDataのentityはPerson)のリストをスワイプで削除するfunctionを書いたのですが、行の削除後に空のセルが表示されたままになります。最下行を消した場合は、消した後に新たにレコードを追加すると、空のセルの下にレコードができます。tableViewのリロードだけで足りないということだと思いますが、どうすればよいでしょうか。
アプリを再起動した場合は、削除された行は空にはならず上に詰めて表示されます。

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var people: [NSManagedObject] = []

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {

        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                          for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let person = people[indexPath.row]

        managedContext.delete(person)

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            people.append(person)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}

}
```

Comment: あなたの削除動作のコードの中に、`people.append(person)`と言う箇所がありますが、どうして要素を **追加**しているのでしょう? ここでも要素を **削除** しないと配列`people`の中身とCore Dataに保存されている内容とが整合しなくなると思うのですが?

Comment: その通りですね。この部分、レコードを作るところから流用してきたのでそのまま残っておりました。修正しました。people.append(person)を削除しただけは問題は解決しないようでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
managedCondext.delete(person)
```

の様にtableViewの行を削除してから`person`を削除してみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: ヒントをいただき、以下のように修正したら行が消えました。tableViewも学習を始めたばかりで理解不足でした。ご指摘ありがとうございました。    //修正箇所 -> people.remove(at: indexPath.row) tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) managedContext.delete(person)   このサイトのコメント欄の入力方法もわかっていなくて申し訳ないです。。。

Comment: ヒントになったようでしたらお役に立てて幸いです